# Cannot download packages on R (neither RStudio nor Terminal)

Tags: linux-mint, r, rstudio

I'm very new to linux, my only experience being using a computer that belonged to somebody else before, meaning that everything was already configured/downloaded and I had no problem doing my job on it, which envolves using some GIS tools and RStudio.

Turns out three days ago I received a new computer form my boss and I decided to maintain the tradition and install linux too. All my co-workers were using Mint 18.3, so I downloaded it and installed it. It turns out it wasn't as straight-forward as I thought.

After reading a bunch of forums and questions posted here, I managed to update my sources.list and insert a CRAN mirror for the download of the latest release of R (3.4.4). RStudio promptly recognized it. However, installing new packages is nearly impossible, as even "native" functionalities, such as *import dataset* are disabled because the packages couldn't be downloaded.

I tried opening R through the terminal and installing packages using the *install.packages* function, but the problem persisted. How can I fix my RStudio in order to install packages correctly?

Below there is a copy of the log (note that I specified the mirror manually):

```
> install.packages("Rcpp",repo="https://cloud.r-project.org/", type="source")
Installing package into ‘/home/iis/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3763400 bytes (3.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2         -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time     -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
/bin/bash: g++: command not found
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: recipe for target 'Date.o' failed
make: *** [Date.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/home/iis/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

Again, since I'm very new to linux, I don't know really which information I should provide to better help you, but please keep in mind that everything is probably on a default/factory setting. If you need additional information I can provide you (given the proper instructions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you begin, many of the R packages depend on the following development tools so go ahead and install them first with `apt-get install`:

```
r-base-dev
```

You can install the R packages via Rstudio via Tools > Install Packages and they will work for R as well. Enter the names of the packages into the field separated by spaces or columns. Sometimes, you'll need Bioconductor to install the packages and you can find that information here:

https://www.bioconductor.org/install/

To give you an overview:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
```

That will set the package source URL for the packages and the script to download and install them.

```
biocLite(c("GenomicFeatures", "AnnotationDbi"))
```

Use that syntax with the package names enclosed in double quotes. It will then proceed with download and installation.

Comment: Hey Nasir, thank you so much for spending your time and giving me such a detailed answer, but unfortunately, those 3 "apt-get install xxxxxx-devel" returned "Unable to locate package". Fortunately, I managed to solve the problem by using `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`, which apparently had the necessary tool to make it work. However, if you have some insight on why I was unable to locate those packages, feel free to contribute. Thank you again.

Comment: That was an error on my part as I am used to working with RHEL and CentOS but it's different for you as your using Mint. I will edit that part in my answer. Were you able to install the R packages afterwards?